# How to play DRM video file in Flutter for Android & iOS app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, drm, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I am developing a flutter app, Where I need to play a DRM video in a flutter for the android app and iOS app. Is there any plugin or player available in flutter? or any example? or any other way?

Available pub: https://pub.dev/packages/drm_video

The above pub is not properly updated.

Please help me. thank you.

Comment: Vlc should easily handle this

Comment: Hi @griffins, thank you for your reply, Vlc can play DRM files also ?

Comment: Played the file from the plugin, played only audio though. you can copy the link and play with your pc vlc

Comment: @griffins, I am developing an app where I need to play DRM files through the app, is there any way available? any player? or plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Better Player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) which has drm configuration, check it.